# Image + Text in DIV and keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, image, css

I have the following requirements:

- I need a `div` with an image + text inside.
- The `div` should keep its aspect ratio and all images inside of the `divs` should have the same height (to do this, I use: [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)).
- The image inside of the `div` should be stretched in order to completely fill the parent `div`.

[I prepared a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5uxz4mx/7/)

I have two main issues:

- As you can see, the left `div` is higher, because it has text inside. This collides with the  `padding-bottom: 150%`-approach which is used to preserve the aspect ratio of the `divs` when their size is changed. The goal, however, is that all `divs` have the same size no matter if/how much text they have inside.
- Moreover, I would like to change the opacity of the background image when I hover the div. However, the text-opacity should not change. I think this can only be achieved via JS. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text as `position:absolute`

```
.inner-text{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
}
.event:hover .inner-text{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}


<div class="bit-3">
  <div class="event" style="background-image: url(https://container25.at/wpdev/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/test.jpg)">
  <div class="inner-text">
      Text inner
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/f5uxz4mx/8/

```css
.bit-3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.event {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding-bottom: 150%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.inner-text{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
 z-index:1;

}
.event:hover .inner-text{
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="bit-3">
  <div class="event" style="background-image: url(https://container25.at/wpdev/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/test.jpg)">
  <div class="inner-text">
      Text inner
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bit-3">
  <div class="event" style="background-image: url(https://container25.at/wpdev/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20170715_mareados.jpg)">
  <div class="inner-text">
      Text inner
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: wow great answer. one more thing: can I make the change in opacity via a smooth transition?

Comment: I could do it with adding `-webkit-transition: background 1000ms;transition: background 1000ms;` to `.inner-text`

Answer (score 0):

try adding background-size: contain;height: 0;

```css
.bit-3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
  max-resolution: res;-left: 20px;
  
  
}

.event {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding-bottom: 150%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bit-3">
  <div class="event" style="background-image: url(https://container25.at/wpdev/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/test.jpg);background-size: contain;height: 0;">asdf text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bit-3">
  <div class="event" style="background-image: url(https://container25.at/wpdev/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20170715_mareados.jpg)">
  </div>
</div>
```